# AWS: Copy all files matching a path to an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy all CSV files in the current directory to my S3 bucket. I'm trying:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket --include '*.CSV'
```

But I get:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: too few arguments
```

I'm reading [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) but there's no example I can see of uploading a list of files.

If I try:

```
aws s3 cp *.CSV s3://openprescribing
```

I get:

```
Unknown options: file1.CSV,file2.CSV
```

Any ideas? The docs also talk about `sync` and include examples of lists of files, but it's not clear to me whether that means copying or syncing files. Same with `mv` which I suspect may mean deleting the files locally.

Comment: `sync` will copy all changes from `A` and put them in `B`, be that your local and S3 - you may be able to add filename filters to it, not sure. *Edit:* yeah, the [documentation for `sync`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#options) looks like you should be able to use that include parameter on it

Comment: OK, having read the docs again, what I didn't understand is that you have to specify a `local path` with s3 commands, which is different from a Unix-style list of filenames. So `aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket --include '*.CSV'` does the trick - the missing `.` for the current directory was the problem.

Comment: I'm still not clear whether `sync` just uploads files, or whether it uploads and then does two-way sync like Dropbox or SugarSync. I hope the former!

Comment: Regarding source and target, yes - the CLI commands need both. I've been using sync for a long time and I've never encountered a two way sync. It's a sync in terms of file diffs from A to B, not the other way (unless you switch A and B around in your command).

Answer (score -1):

You need to add double quotes around your source pattern:
`aws s3 cp "*.CSV" s3://openprescribing`

Then it should work. It happened to me before.

Comment: This doesn't work. Using the `aws sync . s3://<name> --include=".csv"` from the comment above does work